# C# Excel Interop Shapes.AddPicture Image Size Incorrect After 2nd attempt to export to excel files

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

Currently I'm using the `Excel.Interop.Shapes.AddPicture` method to add the picture into my excel files.

Initially, all working great when first Compile the program and export it into excel. But 2nd time export to excel and so on, the picture become smaller and randomly become bigger which not following to the Width and Height that i set on the Excel Object.

It should be everything i export to excel, the image size will be 270 x 198. However if i Re-compile the program and export, the first time export file's image all was fine, but 2nd attempt to export file and so on with running program the image size will randomly become smaller and larger.

Please advice me if anything i did wrong on my export method.

Here are the code that i use to export to Excel :

```
private void btnPhotoExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Workbooks objBooks;
    Excel.Sheets objSheets;
    Excel._Worksheet objSheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
    Excel.Range range;
    // Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
    SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2;

    // Declare of Excel Instance
    objApp = new Excel.Application();
    objBooks = objApp.Workbooks;
    objBook = objBooks.Add(Type.Missing);
    objSheets = objBook.Worksheets;

    List<String> photoList = new List<string>();
    List<String> photoDescriptionList = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < photoDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (photoDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Photo Path"].Value != null)
        {
            photoList.Add(photoDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Photo Path"].Value.ToString());
            photoDescriptionList.Add(photoDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Photo Descriptions"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    // Check file exist
    bool isFileExist = false;

    if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(saveDialog.FileName + ".xlsx"))
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("File '" + saveDialog.FileName + ".xlsx" + "' Already Exist.\nAre You Sure To Overwrite?", "Microsoft Excel",
 MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
                switch (result)
                {
                    case DialogResult.OK:
                        {
                            isFileExist = false; // Does not exist file. Create new one
                            break;
                        }
                    case DialogResult.Cancel:
                        {
                            isFileExist = true; // User Cancel To Overwrite
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isFileExist = false; // Does not exist file. Create new one
            }

            if (!isFileExist)
            {
                #region Photo Report Export Excel
                int row = 120;
                int column = 120;        // If got added new column, then need to minus 1 from here
                // Instantiate Excel and start a new workbook.
                objSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)objSheets.get_Item(1);
                objSheet.Name = "Maintenance & Activity Photos";

                // Get the range where the starting cell has the address
                // m_sStartingCell and its dimensions are m_iNumRows x m_iNumCols.
                range = objSheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);
                range = range.get_Resize(row, column);

                // Create an array.
                string[,] saRet = new string[row + 1, column];

                #region Header
                // Header
                saRet[0, 0] = "LOJI RAWATAN AIR BANGKAP";
                objSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1").Merge();
                objSheet.Range["A1", "A1"].Font.Bold = true;
                objSheet.Range["A1", "A1"].Font.Size = 22;
                objSheet.Range["A1", "A1"].Font.Color = Color.Blue;
                objSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                objSheet.Columns["A"].ColumnWidth += 70;
                objSheet.get_Range("A1", "A2").Merge();

                saRet[2, 0] = "Operation & Maintenance: Harmony Water Sendirian Berhad";
                objSheet.Range["A3", "A3"].Font.Size = 12;
                objSheet.get_Range("A3", "C3").Merge();
                objSheet.get_Range("A3", "A3").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                saRet[2, 3] = "Date: Wednesday, 11 January 2017";
                objSheet.Range["A3", "A3"].Font.Size = 12;
                objSheet.get_Range("A3", "A3").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;

                saRet[3, 0] = "Activity & Maintenance Photos";
                objSheet.Range["A4", "A4"].Font.Size = 12;
                objSheet.Range["A4", "A4"].Font.Underline = true;
                objSheet.get_Range("A4", "B4").Merge();
                objSheet.get_Range("A4", "A4").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
                #endregion

                #region Main Content Photo and Description
                for (int k = 0; k < photoList.Count; k++ )
                {
                    string pDescription = photoDescriptionList[k].ToString();
                    if (pDescription == "")
                    {
                        pDescription = "NULL";
                    }
                    if (k == 0 || k == 1 || k == 2 || k == 3)           // First Page
                    {
                        #region First Page

                        if(k == 0)
                        {
                            // First Page, First Row (Left Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 5, 85, 270, 198);
                            saRet[18, 0] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["A19", "A19"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A19", "B19").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("A19", "A19").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A1", "A20").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Left
                            objSheet.get_Range("D1", "D20").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Right
                            objSheet.get_Range("A20", "D20").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Bottom
                        }
                        else if(k == 1)
                        {
                            // First Page, First Row (Right Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 420, 85, 270, 198);
                            saRet[18, 2] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["C19", "C19"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("C19", "D19").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("C19", "C19").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                        }
                        else if(k == 2)
                        {
                            // First Page , Second Row (Left Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 5, 330, 270, 198);
                            saRet[34, 0] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["A35", "A35"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A35", "B35").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("A35", "A35").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A20", "A36").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Left
                            objSheet.get_Range("D20", "D36").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Right
                            objSheet.get_Range("A36", "D36").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Bottom
                        }
                        else if(k == 3)
                        {
                            // First Page, Second Row (Right Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 420, 330, 270, 198);
                            saRet[34, 2] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["C35", "C35"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("C35", "D35").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("C35", "C35").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                    else if (k == 4 || k == 5 || k == 6 || k == 7)     // Second Page
                    {
                        #region Second Page
                        if (k == 4)
                        {
                            // Second Page, First Row (Left Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 5, 375 + (1 * 245 - (1 * 5)), 270, 198);
                            saRet[53, 0] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["A54", "A54"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A54", "B54").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("A54", "A54").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A40", "D40").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Top
                            objSheet.get_Range("A40", "A55").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Left
                            objSheet.get_Range("D40", "D55").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Right
                            objSheet.get_Range("A55", "D55").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Bottom

                        }
                        else if(k == 5)
                        {
                            // Second Page, First Row (Right Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 420, 375 + (1 * 245 - (1 * 5)), 270, 198);
                            saRet[53, 2] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["C54", "C54"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("C54", "D54").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("C54", "C54").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;

                        }
                        else if(k == 6)
                        {
                            // Second Page, Second Row (Left Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 5, 375 + (2 * 245 - (2 * 5)), 270, 198);
                            saRet[69, 0] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["A70", "A70"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A70", "B70").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("A70", "A70").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A55", "A71").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Left
                            objSheet.get_Range("D55", "D71").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Right
                            objSheet.get_Range("A71", "D71").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Bottom
                        }
                        else if(k == 7)
                        {
                            // Second Page, Second Row (Right Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 420, 375 + (2 * 245 - (2 * 5)), 270, 198);
                            saRet[69, 2] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["C70", "C70"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("C70", "D70").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("C70", "C70").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;

                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                    else if (k == 8 || k == 9 || k == 10 || k == 11)    // Third Page
                    {
                        #region Third Page
                        if (k == 8)
                        {
                            // Third Page, First Row (Left Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 5, 465 + (3 * 245 - (3 * 5)), 270, 198);
                            saRet[91, 0] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["A92", "A92"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A92", "B92").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("A92", "A92").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A78", "D78").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Top
                            objSheet.get_Range("A78", "A93").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Left
                            objSheet.get_Range("D78", "D93").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Right
                            objSheet.get_Range("A93", "D93").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Bottom

                        }
                        else if (k == 9)
                        {
                            // Third Page, First Row (Right Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 420, 465 + (3 * 245 - (3 * 5)), 270, 198);
                            saRet[91, 2] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["C92", "C92"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("C92", "D92").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("C92", "C92").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                        }
                        else if (k == 10)
                        {
                            // Third Page, Second Row (Left Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 5, 465 + (4 * 245 - (4 * 5)), 270, 198);
                            saRet[107, 0] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["A108", "A108"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A108", "B108").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("A108", "A108").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                            objSheet.get_Range("A93", "A109").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Left
                            objSheet.get_Range("D93", "D109").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Right
                            objSheet.get_Range("A109", "D109").Borders.get_Item(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; // Draw on the Bottom
                        }
                        else if (k == 11)
                        {
                            // Third Page, Second Row (Right Photo)
                            objSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"" + photoList[k].ToString(), Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 420, 465 + (4 * 245 - (4 * 5)), 270, 198);
                            saRet[107, 2] = pDescription; // Picture Description
                            objSheet.Range["C108", "C108"].Font.Size = 10;
                            objSheet.get_Range("C108", "D108").Merge();
                            objSheet.get_Range("C108", "C108").Cells.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion

                }
                objSheet.Columns["C"].ColumnWidth += 15; // Extend the column "C" Width
                objSheet.Columns["B"].ColumnWidth = 0;  // Hide Column B which is unused
                #endregion

                // Draw Border
                objSheet.get_Range("A1", "D3").Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;  // Draw header border

                objSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;
                // Normal Margins
                objSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = objApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5);
                objSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = objApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5);
                objSheet.PageSetup.TopMargin = objApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5);
                objSheet.PageSetup.BottomMargin = objApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5);
                objSheet.PageSetup.HeaderMargin = objApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5);
                objSheet.PageSetup.FooterMargin = objApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5);
                // Fit Sheet on One Page 
                objSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
                objSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1;
                // Set the range value to the array.
                range.set_Value(Missing.Value, saRet);
                objSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
                objApp.DisplayAlerts = false;   // Temporary disable the alert box
                objBook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
                MessageBox.Show("Excel File Is Saved At :\n" + saveDialog.FileName, "Success");                    
                #endregion
            }
        }
        catch (Exception theException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(theException.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Operation Canceled.", "Failed To Save");
        }
        finally
        {
            photoList.Clear();
            photoDescriptionList.Clear();
            objApp.Quit();
            objBook = null;
            objApp = null;

            // Release All Excel Object
            releaseObject(objSheet);
            releaseObject(objSheets);
            releaseObject(objBook);
            releaseObject(objBooks);
            releaseObject(objApp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Operation Canceled.", "Failed To Save");
    }
}
```